# Notebook with SSD: Added a HDD and now hibernation and shutdown are slow

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, ssd, shutdown, hibernate

I have an Asus N56VZ notebook. It have a 1 TiB SSD on which I installed windows 8.1. I used this configuration for about 2 years. Yesterday I added a 2 TiB HDD and now the hibernate is very slow and also the shutdown takes extremely much time.

I think the hibernate file should be stored on `C:\`? This is the SSD which means it should be fast.

I also checked the BIOS if the HDD is the first boot option, but it is disabled, so this shouldn't be a problem.

Has anyone an idea what's the problem?

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk which also works for 8.1), run WPRUI.exe, select "First Level", under  Resource select **CPU usage**, **DiskIO**, **FileIO** and under **Performance Scenario** select **Hibernation/Resume**. **Number of iteration** can be set to **1** and click to start. This hibernates the device and resumes it and captures the activity. Repeat this also for a shutdown option under **Performance Scenario**. Zip both large ETL files into zip/RAR file, upload the zip (OneDrive) and post the share link here.

Comment: Unfortunately i took the harddisk case (http://www.ebay.de/itm/2nd-Hard-Drive-HDD-SSD-Caddy-For-ASUS-N56VZ-N56VZ-DS71-N56VZ-ES71-N56JN-re-UJ8E1-/390559868289) and changed the state of a switch inside it (which is not described). Since i did this, the harddisk is no longer recognized by the operating system. I also changed the switch state to the initial state, but it no longer works. So I removed the harddisk and I use now an external one. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is no longer reproducible and no longer needs to be answered.

Comment: @Kevin, it sounds like you could be dealing with a faulty 2 TB HDD or there's something wrong with the connectivity to it. When the system is trying to read a faulty or somehow corrupted HDD, it could affect the overall performance, regardless of the booting/system drive being a healthy SSD. I'd advise you to check how this particular drive is performing in another working PC/laptop and see if your notebook will behave properly, once this new drive is unplugged. Keep us posted!

Comment: I used an external 2.5" HDD case and inserted the (maybe faulty) HDD there. I use it now on another PC to synchronize some data on it. It seems to work well. On the other hand i did not use any tool to test it (i only used rsync to write a few hundred GiB data). My notebook does work now without any problems.